# Matrix Algebra!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If we have a matrix multiplication equation,

$$s=A^\top \cdot P \cdot B,$$

Where $s$ is an integer and I have to find the matrix $P$. How would I use matrix alegbra here, since $A$ and $B$ are vectors and therefore the inverse cannot be found.

Thanks :)

Comment: The value of $P$ is not unique. If you can find $Q$ such that $A^\top Q B=r\not=0$, then you can let $\displaystyle P= {s\over r}\cdot Q$, for instance.

Comment: @Carl: Since this it The Matrix, I'm guessing the OP is trying to find The One (matrix). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $B$ is nonzero (otherwise $s=0$). So let $B=(b_1,....,b_n)$ and assume $b_i\neq 0$ for some $i$. Then the following choice for $P$ satisfies $A^TPB=s$: Fill $P$ with zeros, but in the $i$-th column, insert $\frac{s}{b_i\lvert|A\rvert|^2}A$. Then $PB=\frac{s}{\lvert|A\rvert|^2}A$. (if $\lvert|A\rvert|=0$, this does not work, but then $A=0$ and $s=0$.)